# ¿Cómo generar una plantilla en jsonnet para URLs de GitHub badges?

Tags: jsonnet

Estoy intentando generar con jsonnet un array que el resultado será las URLs de los badge de cada uno de los workflows en los proyectos de una organización.

Los ficheros de workflow tienen el mismo formato siempre `workflow-project.yaml` y debo excluir ciertos proyectos de la organización.

```
local workflowUrlTemplate = |||
  <a href='https://github.com/%s/%s/actions/workflows/%s' style='display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;'>
    <img src='https://github.com/%s/%s/actions/workflows/%s/badge.svg' alt='workflow" style="max-width: 100%%;'>
  </a>
|||;

local projects = [
  'project1',
  'project2',
];

local workflowFilesPerOrg = {
  adrianfusco: {
    [project]: ['workflow-' + project + '.yaml']
    for project in projects
  },
};

local workflowsUrls = [
  workflowUrlTemplate % [organization, project, workflowFile, organization, project, workflowFile]
  for organization in std.objectFields(workflowFilesPerOrg)
  for project in std.objectFields(workflowFilesPerOrg[organization])
  for workflowFile in workflowFilesPerOrg[organization][project]
];

workflowsUrls
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ello se puede utilizar `!std.member` (forma parte de la [Standard Library](https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html)) en el loop para excluir de un array los elementos del otro.

```
local workflowUrlTemplate = |||
  <a href='https://github.com/%s/%s/actions/workflows/%s' style='display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;'>
    <img src='https://github.com/%s/%s/actions/workflows/%s/badge.svg' alt='workflow" style="max-width: 100%%;'>
  </a>
|||;

local projects = [
  'project1',
  'project2',
];

local projectsWithoutBuildWorkflow = [
  'project3',
  'project4',
];


local workflowFilesPerOrg = {
  adrianfusco: {
    [project]: ['workflow-' + project + '.yaml']
    for project in projects
    if !std.member(projectsWithoutBuildWorkflow, project)
  },
};

local workflowsUrls = [
  workflowUrlTemplate % [organization, project, workflowFile, organization, project, workflowFile]
  for organization in std.objectFields(workflowFilesPerOrg)
  for project in std.objectFields(workflowFilesPerOrg[organization])
  for workflowFile in workflowFilesPerOrg[organization][project]
];

workflowsUrls
```

Esto dará como resultado si lo ejecutamos:

```
$ jsonnet jsonnet/array.jsonnet 
[
   "<a href='https://github.com/adrianfusco/project1/actions/workflows/workflow-project1.yaml' style='display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;'>\n  <img src='https://github.com/adrianfusco/project1/actions/workflows/workflow-project1.yaml/badge.svg' alt='workflow\" style=\"max-width: 100%;'>\n</a>\n",
   "<a href='https://github.com/adrianfusco/project2/actions/workflows/workflow-project2.yaml' style='display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;'>\n  <img src='https://github.com/adrianfusco/project2/actions/workflows/workflow-project2.yaml/badge.svg' alt='workflow\" style=\"max-width: 100%;'>\n</a>\n"
]
```